# To read about / on a topic

Tags: prepositions

Are these two sentences correct?

- I've read a lot **about** this topic lately
- I've read a lot **on** this topic lately

If both are valid, is there any difference in their meaning?

Comment: They are both correct from an English readers perspective.  I think the ON version feels more specific, like you were looking for information, while the ABOUT version feels like the reading was incidental to other readings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plok, both versions are correct and convey the same meaning.

There is usually more than one way to express a thought, however which methods, or methods, one uses depends on context- what you are writing, the audience, etc.

The version using "on" connotes a specific target (as mentioned by baash05) and is also more formal.